# Establishing configurations in new containers

Tags: docker, containers

I am setting up a brand new development environment, nginx+php-fpm and decided to create application containers (using docker) for each service.

Normally I would install nginx and php and modify the configuration (with and editor like vim), reload the services until the services were correctly configured.

To establish a similar procedure starting the initial container and copying the /etc/nginx to the host. Modify the config files in the host and use a docker file (containing another COPY) to test the changes.

Given that the containers are somewhat ephemeral and aren't really meant to contain utilities like vim I was wondering how people set up the initial configuration ?

Once I have a working config I know the options with regards to configuration management for managing the files. It's really the establishment of new containers that I'm curious about.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass configuration through [environment variables](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables) or mount a host file as a [data volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/).

Example for [nginx](https://hub.docker.com/r/_/nginx/) configuration:

```
docker run --name some-nginx -v /yoursystem/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro -d nginx
```

You can use many images from Docker Hub as starting point: [nginx-php-fmp](https://hub.docker.com/r/richarvey/nginx-php-fpm/).